# Can't concatenate Elements with namespaces

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

Very strange behavior with the following XPath expression:

```
//*[local-name() = 'Name']/text(), '-' , //*[local-name() = 'Value']/text()
```

I want to retrieve this from the following SOAP response:
    ...

```
<Case>
   <cam:SpecificCase xmlns:cam="http://my.namespace/CaseManagement">
      <cam:CaseType>Complaint_SenMngt</cam:CaseType>
      <cam:SpecificCaseAttribute>
         <cam:TypeName>Complaint Inquiry Claim Case</cam:TypeName>
         <cam:Name>Content Corrections</cam:Name>
         <cam:Value>false</cam:Value>
      </cam:SpecificCaseAttribute>
      <cam:SpecificCaseAttribute>
         <cam:TypeName>Complaint Inquiry Claim Case</cam:TypeName>
         <cam:Name>Formal Corrections</cam:Name>
         <cam:Value>false</cam:Value>
      </cam:SpecificCaseAttribute>
      <cam:SpecificCaseAttribute>
         <cam:TypeName>Complaint Inquiry Claim Case</cam:TypeName>
         <cam:Name>Complexity</cam:Name>
     </cam:SpecificCaseAttribute>
</Case>
```

I get the following Error in XMLSpy:

```
Wrong occurrence to match required sequence type
    Details
        XPTY0004: The parameter value ('15' item(s)) at position '1' of the 'concat' function has the wrong occurrence to match the sequence type xs:anyAtomicType ('zero or one')
```

Comment: If you get an error on a `concat` function call then your posted code should show a concat function call. And you need to tell us which result you want for the XML sample posted, there are three `cam:Name` and two `cam:Value` elements the path `//*[local-name() = 'Name']/text()` respectively `//*[local-name() = 'Value']/text()` selects while each argument to concat needs to be a single item.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your xslt processor can't decide which of three names/values to choose. Saxon 9 works well with this xpath and chooses first Name and first Value, so, knowing nothing about your xslt processor (I guess that it's an old version saxon because error code is xpath2-specific), I'd suggest to rewrite your xpath:

```
concat(//*[local-name() = 'Name']/text()[1], '-' , //*[local-name() = 'Value']/text()[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you first correct your XML to be well-formed by adding a closing `</cam:SpecificCase>` tag, this XPath:

```
concat((//*[local-name() = 'Name'])[1], '-' , (//*[local-name() = 'Value'])[1])
```

Will evaluate to the concatenated string values of the first `cam:Name` and `cam:Value` elements:

```
'Content Corrections-false'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output all values then one way is for example shown in http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHTd, it has

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
  xmlns:cam="http://my.namespace/CaseManagement" exclude-result-prefixes="cam">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="cam:SpecificCase">
    <example1>
      <xsl:value-of select="cam:SpecificCaseAttribute/concat(cam:Name, '-', cam:Value)"/> 
    </example1>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

and for your input sample outputs

```
<example1>Content Corrections-false Formal Corrections-false Complexity-</example1>
```